# How to display the output (query result) from an update query which is executed by a powershell script?

Tags: oracle, powershell

On a daily basis, I need to update certain number of records in a DB.

Now to update this DB, I am using **Merge** --> **Select**--> **Update** sequentially.

But I need to display the output from this update statement (in a log file)

Code: **update_status.ps1**

```
$FilePath = $HOME+"\bin\ORACLE_CONNECTION_HOME\oracle_config.properties"

$SID=Select-String -Pattern "oracle_SID" -Path $FilePath 
$Data_Source=$SID.ToString().split('=')[1]

$user_name=Select-String -Pattern "oracle_user_name" -Path $FilePath
$User=$user_name.ToString().split('=')[1]

$user_password=Select-String -Pattern "oracle_user_password" -Path $FilePath
$Pwd=$user_password.ToString().split('=')[1]

$connectionString= "Data Source=$Data_Source;User Id=$User;Password=$Pwd;Integrated Security=no"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient") | Out-Null 
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString)

function Oracle_Connection ( $query)
{
$connectionString= "Data Source=$Data_Source;User Id=$User;Password=$Pwd;Integrated Security=no"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient") | Out-Null 
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$queryString = $query 
$command = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand($queryString, $connection) 
$connection.Open()
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$oracleadapter = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter $command
$resultcount = $oracleadapter.fill($dataset)
$result = $command.ExecuteScalar()
Write-Host $result
$connection.Close()

}

function Update_p2c ($p2c, $c2p)
{
Write-Host "Updating P2C"
$query_sub_p2c ="MERGE INTO TABLE TB USING (SELECT ...) src ON ( NAME = src.NAME) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TB.P2C = src.ID";
Oracle_Connection $query_p2c
if ($resultcount -gt 0) { Write-Host "$resultcount rows were updated"} else {Write-Host "No rows were updated"}
}

##Initial setup completed.

#Defining Source and Target variables used in functions
$p2c = 'P2C'
$c2p = 'C2P'


Update_p2c -p2c $p2c -c2p $c2p
##End
```

Result:

```
PS D:\
Updating P2C

No rows were updated
```

However, I see that when I run the select & update manually in DB, I can see the rows getting selected as well as updated respectively.

This script is triggered by a .bat file in a task scheduler and it generates a log file

bat file:

```
pushd "%~dp0"


start /B /WAIT powershell -File "D:\bin\update_status.ps1" >> D:\log\update_status_%USERNAME%_%date%_log.log 2>&1

exit
```

My requirement is: I need to get the output from the update ( so and so rows updated from db) into the log file. Even if no rows get updated, it should show the same.

Please let me know if my ask is not clear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the content of $result written to a logfile?

Comment: yes, I need to track the updated rows in the logfile.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you do not need a batch to run a powershell script from the task scheduler.

```
Task -> Actions -> Program/script = powershell.exe
Task -> Actions -> Add arguments = -File "D:\bin\update_status.ps1"
```

If the data you are looking for ist stored in the variable $result, simply wirte  it to the logfile:

```
$result | set-content "D:\log\update_status_$($env:username)_$(get-date -format 'yyyy-dd-MM')_log.log"
```

Note $env:username will always be the caller identity of the scheduled task.

Comment: hi Toni, My project only allows .bat files to be used to run a powershell script, Hence cannot change that. For the write to log file, where exactly should this be used? Is it in the function or on the body of the script where I call the function?

Comment: I would let the function return the objects it changed and write the logfile outside of the function. If $result contains the information you need to add ```return $result``` after ```$connection.Close()``` and call the function like this ```$result = Oracle_Connection $query```, after that you have the information stored in $result and you can write this information to the disk with set-content/export-csv or convert it to json - depends on the data structure you get back

Comment: I've tried this approach, but still getting the issue. There is not output from $result. Its just blank

Comment: I've tried another method now. Instead of MERGE, I am only using SELECT now. Everything would be same, but instead of Update_ function, I've created a new select_ function to get the output (ids) from query and write into a log file. But this time, Only the first record is the seen in the log, How do I get the rest of the records inside the log? Array method? Please suggest @Toni

Comment: `function Select_id ($source, $target, $length, $sid)
{
Write-Host "ids to update"
$select_query = "SELECT  ...";
Oracle_Connection $select_query
return $select_query
}` `Select_id -source $p2c -target $c2p -length $length -sid $sid_p2c`